# Remote desktop not passing all mouse buttons

Tags: mouse, vnc, remote-access, logitech

I have a Logitech mouse with tilt wheel buttons. When I am using it locally on a system using Ubuntu 19.10 with the 5.3.0-40-generic kernel, it works as expected.

When I connect to the same system using remote desktop server apps and a vnc viewer client on Windows 10, the two tilt buttons are not seen by the system.

[xev](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/xev.1.html) shows buttons 1-5, but the tilt buttons on the scroll wheel do not generate anything. I have tried 3 or 4 vnc viewers, and on the server side tried [x0vncserver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/x0vnc4server.1.html) as well as remote desktop. In all cases these two buttons are just not passed to the server. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/x0vnc4server.1.html shows there's no x0vncserver release for 19.10 . So far, I see you have tried just one supported Ubuntu remote server app; others are listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support and you can click in the Linux Server column to sort those out.

Comment: x0vncserver was installed with TigerVNC: TigerVNC Server version 1.9.0, built Dec  1 2018 21:51:29. Neither it nor the Tiger vncserver was very stable for me. So far the built-in Ubuntu Screen Sharing has worked flawlessly except for this mouse button issue.
Thanks for the link, I will look at some to the other vnc servers there.